# How to get profile picture of facebook users by a specific region?

Tags: image, facebook, get, screen-scraping

I'm setting up a machine learning application and I want to know if there is any way to get profiles pictures of Facebook users just with a specific region?

For e.g: get profile pictures of the Facebook user of the region of Paris.

I have an idea about web scraping but I don't know if this technique can help with this task or no?
Thanks.

Comment: Facebook Terms of Service does not allow you to scrape them. And you can only get profile pictures from people that given permission to your app to access their profile pictures.

Comment: Okey thanks, what about tools using for social engineering? ( for e.g: social engineering toolkit ).

Comment: No idea what you mean

Comment: Ok, no problem, Thanks